# jquery simple code not working(id is assigned to the button)

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

This is the sample code that i am learning from w3schools. This time i have given the id too to the button. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("#div1").fadeIn();
                $("#div2").fadeIn("slower");
                $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Try jQuery</h2>
    <br /><button>Click me</button>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;color:green"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="width:80px;height:80px;color:yellow"></div>
    <div id="div3" style="width:80px;height:80px;color:blanchedalmond"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the link of the jquery written in the comment is the one i dowloaded from http://jquery.com/download/ ... and it didn't work so i used the url instead . Please reply .

Comment: please read up on how jQuery works and at least get to understand how selectors work. There is a full section dedicated to selectors in the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned your script is looking for something with the ID attribute 'hide' as indicated in your jQuery $('#hide').

There are many different ways to select everything in your dom.  Have a look at the jquery documentation.  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/  The simplicity of selecting dom elements is what makes jQuery so powerful in my opinion.

Select by ID:

```
$('#id')
```

You can select every even row in a table.

```
$('table tr:even')
```

You can select the 14th div element in the dom.

```
$('div:eq(14)')
```

You can select all elements with a given class.

```
$('.class')
```

Here is a JSfiddle with the code in a working fashion.

**http://jsfiddle.net/5v94cnrr/**

It looks like the button is ID 'hide' and it will hide all P elements on click.  Typically you'd use a class called hide and hide all element with class hide on click of the button or some other action.

Comment: that really will help. But i have added the "id" to "hide" , after which still doesnt work!

Comment: please see my question again.. i have updated and put another code.. PLease help me in that code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#hide").click(function () ...
```

this line of code basically means "when an element with id 'hide' is clicked, do something". So your button is missing that id

```
<button id="hide">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and paste it. It works. Tested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#hide").click(function () {
                $("p").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Try jQuery</h2>
    <p>This will get hide</p>
    <button id="hide">CLick Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that worked @MdShawon. But if you could please tell me what is the error in my code! so that it helps me in future learning..

Comment: Just edited this line. You missed id. **<button id="hide">CLick Me</button>**

Answer (score 0):

You have not set `#hide` for anything. If you need it on a button, do:

```
<button id="hide">CLick Me</button>
```

Comment: Then, it looks like you are having problems with adding jquery library. Try using this: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: the link you have given is the exactly the same I have used.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide p tag elements on onclick of button.

So firstly, you have to provide id for this button because you are making click function on button.

Try this:

```
<button id='hide'>Click Me</button>
```